# Trying to center a column inside a container in HTML CSS, CSS not working

Tags: html, css

i'M TRYING TO CENTER THE COLUMN INSIDE A CONTAINER BUT IT GOES LEFT SIDE. i have tried css properties, what am i doing wrong ? I have reduced the width of paragraph container to 650px or somewhere 70%, it goes left sided when i set the width.

```
   <letstalk>
<div className="container">
  <div className="row">
     <h1>Escape is not his plan.
       I must face him, alone.</h1>
       <div className="col">
      <p className="textcontent"> As you wish. I can't get involved! I've got work to do! 
        It's not that I like the Empire, I hate it, but there's nothing 
        I can do about it right now. It's such a long way from here. Alderaan? 
        I'm not going to Alderaan.
        I've got to go home. It's late, I'm in for it as it is.</p>
        </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Talk</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

````

//css

```
letstalk {
 height: auto;
 background: #2D2828;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 color: white;
 padding: 50px;
 .container{
     justify-content: center;
     text-align: center;
      }
      .textcontent {
          max-width: 650px;
      }
```

}

[This is the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyeQE.png)

i want that paragraph to be center rather than left side. I set the width 60% or 650px, to that paragraph only.
Can anyone help me what i did wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add margin:0 auto; to this class

```css
.textcontent {
          max-width: 650px;
          margin:0 auto;
 }
```

.textcontent

Answer (score 0):

if `display: block` and the parent block has no effect - `margin: 0 auto` else set parent block `display: flex; justify-content: center`

Answer (score 0):

add margin, I added 5px

```
.textcontent {
      max-width: 650px;
      margin: 5px auto;
  }
```